# Jupyter note book path not found

Tags: python, compiler-errors, jupyter-notebook, coding-style, filepath

1. I have tried to locate the file. used both forward and backwards also I have used 1 and 2 apostrophes - nothing has changed
2. This is the error I am getting
   [image: Error I'm Getting]

Answer (score 0):

Windows is a bit trickier. This is jut a hunch but maybe try:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\BarbieA\\.... "
```

Windows paths are separated by `\` but since that is used to escape special characters, you would need to escape it as well, so it becomes `\\`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I recommend using pathlib  to make your life easier, as sometimes, the spaces and the special symbols can be confusing when writing by hand.

```
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
file = PureWindowsPath(r"C:\Users\Barbie..")
open(file)
```